# Build error when using Cordova google-analytics-plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add https://github.com/nickdrewe/google-analytics-plugin to my cordova project. But the build failed. Here are what I tried:

1. Install google playservices 21 instead of 19. Edit plugin.xml to point to 21 but still don't work.
2. Remove google playservices completely and use framework instead https://github.com/nickdrewe/google-analytics-plugin/commit/cb8e78f17472ae2c8b4db613273764a7260b4e34 but still build error
3. I also tried `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"` from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/UXW0Hl0UVXk

The error I got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify build listener.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

/vagrant/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /vagrant/MyProject/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/vagrant/MyProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /vagrant/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /vagrant/MyProject/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I am using Ionic 1.5.5 and Cordova Android 4.0.2

Any help?

I am open to alternative Google Analytics plugin but I found https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin causing Android app crashing upon start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your error - and there is none. I build a new project with the plugin you linked and also the console plugin. The build was totaly fine and successfull.

As far as i see you edited your gradle build settings for speeding up the gradle build. `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true`... as far as i read through the documents this must be `-org.gradle.daemon=true` or is the `D` sth like an operator or a variable which has to be there?

What you can also try is to run the `cmd` as an administrator.

Cordova downgrade from 5.1.1 to 4.3.2 fixed the problem for many users.

Comment: Do you use cordova straight or with Ionic? Which Android SDK version? OS? Since I do mine on Mac.

Comment: Doin mine on mac also, android at 4.0.2 - cordova straight, no ionic. I'm just taking a deeper look into your issue.

Comment: you've already seen this, haven't you? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/282

Comment: Yes, and I tried few options including `android:targetSdkVersion="22"`. I probably need to downgrade Cordova CLI next and run `build.bat --debug`

Comment: Hmm I reinstalled everything: Android SDK, Cordova CLI, Ionic.. and got the build to work. The `window.analytics` object exists but I cannot get any event recorded real-time in my GA Mobile account. Grrr...

Comment: Yes, but that seems to be a problem with the plugin or sth else. The acutal question with your build error is solved than. I would recommend you, to open up another question belonging to your problem now. :-)